# ERROR AL CREAR una carpeta android studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando crear una carpeta en el almacenamiento interno (donde el usuario del dispositivo pueda acceder a esa carpeta) en android studio (usando java). Si la carpeta esta creada, no quiero crearla de nuevo.

Quiero guardarla aquí
[image]:

He visitado varios links como este: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124612/android-create-folders-in-internal-memory pero no he encontrado lo que quiero. Quiero que la carpeta sea accesible para el usuario, no quiero guardarla aquí /data/data/package.name/app_MyDirName, por ejemplo.

He probado este código pero siempre da error:

```
    public void createFolder(View v){
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_HERE");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            if(folder.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("App","file created successfully");
            }else{
                Log.d("App","error creating folder");
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("App","folder exists");
        }
    }
```

Este es el resultado del logcat

```
2020-12-26 17:56:17.433 5981-5981/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-12-26 17:56:17.434 5981-5981/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-12-26 17:56:17.508 5981-5981/? E/mple.pruebadoc: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-12-26 17:56:18.878 5981-9037/com.example.pruebadocs E/gralloc: Arm Module v1.0
2020-12-26 17:56:18.879 5981-9037/com.example.pruebadocs E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

Este es mi manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pruebadocs">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PruebaDocs"
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Siempre recibo el mensaje: "error creating folder message" pero no sé porque.
Estaría muy agradecido si alguien pudiese ayudarme!

Comment: tienes los permisos de escritura y lectura ent u manifiest?  es >= android Q?

Comment: @OsAndNoTi he añadido mi manifest a la pregunta

Comment: En el LogCat busca donde diga "Caused by"

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> Estoy intentando crear una carpeta en el almacenamiento interno (donde
> el usuario del dispositivo pueda acceder a esa carpeta)

para crear una carpeta en el almacenamiendo interno debes usar [**getFilesDir()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()):

```
File folder = new File(getFilesDir(),"YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_HERE");
```

Esto creara el directorio en :

```
/data/data/package name/"YOUR_FOLDER_NAME_HERE"
```

Comment: Pero esto sería información privada para la app, que el usuario no puede acceder y si se desinstala la app también se borraría esta información, no?